# Limit number of images - Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, polymorphism

I have `User` model with the following association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes :pictures
end
```

My `Picture` model looks like this:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

Now, I want to user to be able to upload maximum 5 images. And he will select 1 image as his avatar. Now, user can upload images but I don't know how to limit the maximum number of pictures. One more thing, user needs to be able to change his avatar image. How can I achieve this?

In my view, I use input file with name `user[picture_attributes][0][image]` in order to allow user to change the first picture but it keeps inserting new pictures into database instead of replacing the first picture.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the problem you have, i would suggest you use rails built-in counter_cache method.

Your picture model would thus become:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true, counter_cache: true
    has_attached_file :image
end
```

Also you would need to add a column called pictures_count to the User model.

This way in your controller you could check if the count is upto 5 records and therefore inform them that they have uploaded the maximum allowed.

```
if @user.pictures.size == 5 #sorry no more uploads
```

For the second part of the problem. Is the form action pointed to the new/create action or to your update action. If pointed to the new action a new record would be created but if pointed to the update action then it should change the first image record as you expect.

@charinten For the second part of the problem, some suggestions:

1. You could try making the id of the pictures accessible in the user model. This way when you try to  point to the image to use as an avatar, rails uses that id to update the record.  If you try to update the record without pointing rails to that id, it would assume you are trying to create a new record.
2. Also rather than using user[picture_attributes][0][image] you could in your user profile. Find a specific image and point to that image on the edit action.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. I don't know why but my form is for update method and it keeps inserting new images to database.

Comment: If you could paste a snippet of the code in your view as well as your update method i would have a look and see how i might be able to help on that. Also i do not understand why you would do this user[picture_attributes][0][image].

Comment: Actually, it is a legacy code from previous developer. As I understand, he wants to use the first picture as the avatar for an user.

Comment: Ok then. Update your question by showing snippets of the form and also your update action in the controller so i can look through it and see the problem.